# WCF "Too many active security negotiations" error in production

Tags: wcf, exception, config

We have a WCF service that over 100 client sites make calls to. Today we started getting the

```
Exception: Server 'http://[url]/services/[service].svc/ws' sent back a     
fault indicating it is too busy to process the request. Please retry later. Please see the 
inner exception for fault details.
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: There are too many active security negotiations or 
secure conversations at the service. Please retry later.
```

The only information I could find is that I need to make the `maxPendingSessions` larger. But that would require changing the endpoint to a CustomBinding, which will be difficult because I'd have to push that to all of my client sites.

Is there some way I can just "reset" the number of security negotiations and such? This would give us time to change the client program to use the custom binding, because at the moment, our sites cannot talk to our server.
I've tried making a small change to the config file and saving, which should have restarted the service, but we're still getting errors.

Or is there some other way I could handle this?

**Edit** Here's my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings,     Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
          </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\logs\log.txt" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
        <services>
       <service name="WCFServiceLibrary.WCFService">
     <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding"     bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWCFService"
      name="WSHttpEndpoint_IWCFService" contract="WCFServiceLibrary.IWCFService" />
     <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              name="BasicHttpEndpoint_IWCFService"             contract="WCFServiceLibrary.IWCFService" />
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
   </service>
  </services>
    <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWCFService" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536"     maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"     negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=[url]" storeLocation="LocalMachine"     storeName="TrustedPeople" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"     certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls ="1001" maxConcurrentSessions="1001"     maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug     includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**
We tried an `iisreset` and even restarted the server and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Sounds like you have a singleton service with a session constraint of some kind. It would help if you put information on the service contract setup and configuration in your question.

Comment: @Sixto Yes it is. It's hosted in IIS. I've added my config.

Comment: Recycling the app pool will answer your reset question, but not solve your problem.

you problem can be caused by other factors than your app, since you are using certificates. How is your CA setup?

Comment: In your reply, it seems you are saying that it was a singleton service hosted in IIS. The config you are showing is not a singleton configuration. Are using a custom service factory to instantiate the service in IIS or you just using the standard IIS set up for the service? Also, it would be good to know if you are setting the ConcurrencyMode and InstanceContextMode attribute values in your service contract.

Comment: @Frode I've recycled the correct app pool and clients are still throwing the error. I'm using a self-signed CA, but I don't think that is the problem because everything has worked for the past couple of months until today. Could this be caused by another service I have using the same app pool?

Comment: @Sixto Standard IIS settings. ConcurrencyMode = Multiple, and not setting the InstanceContextMode. I've obviously misunderstood the meaning of singleton service.

Comment: If the error is new, check your last windows updates... :)

Comment: Try to reset Windows Process Activation Service as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/wcf/thread/a8f82f1d-e824-474e-84ef-b5e9ba7eca18

Problem is creating client but not using it (not calling any method on it).

http://litemedia.info/there-are-too-many-active-security-negotiations-or-secure-conversations-at-the-service

I spent 4 days investigating this in .NET 4.0 to realise it is NOT fixed.

Repro is easy:

```
ChannelFactory<IFoo> foo = new ChannelFactory<IFoo>("binding");
foo.Open();
foo.Close();
```

After 128 calls you get the error.

I do not know why it is not fixed but **solution is to create the proxy when you are sure you need to call it.** Increasing maxPending noy really useful as you might still hit the threashold.

Comment: How to create "proxy when you are sure you need to call it"? I am having the same problem and your post is promising but frustrating at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're not using a custom service factory then you're not creating a singleton service hosted in IIS. The issue may be related to setting your service to run multi-threaded. Unless your service contains code that depends/manages multiple threads, you should configure the service instanciation to be single threaded. Set ConcurrencyMode = Single and remove the serviceThrottling element from the config to use the built-in WCF defaults for these. If the exceptions go away then you're done. Otherwise, you'll know it wasn't the multi-threaded configuration or the service throttling settings.

Comment: Wouldn't setting ConcurrencyMode = Single limit me to one call at a time? That won't scale well, and I don't want my clients having to wait for others to finish.

Comment: WCF with IIS and the config you have in your question will spin up a service instance per WCF session (which is completely **independent** from the ASP.NET session). This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) has a detailed overview of WCF sessions. Either per-call or per-session InstanceContextMode settings are very scalable. What ConcurrencyMode controls is whether each service instance is allowed to be multi-threaded or not.